# Use a function without writing the name out, but by using info in a variable in python

Tags: python

I'm sorry if this has already showed up, but couldn't find a solution for this in other questions.  I want to do something like this:

```
var1 = 'print'
coolfunction(var1, 'aaa') # I want this to be the same as print('aaa')
```

So the goal is to use the information stored in a variable and use it to specify the function that is going to be used.

Is there any way I can do something like this in Python?

I have tried

```
globals()['print']('will this work?')
```

but this didn't work.

Comment: Why do you need to pass the _name_ of the function? Why not pass the function itself? `var1 = print`…

Comment: It's unsafe depending on how you're using it but you could use `exec`.

Comment: lambda expression may help  [link] (https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/operators/lambda.html)

Comment: Thanks for the many solutions!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`print` is a builtin function. So you can do something like the following

```
>>> import builtins
>>> getattr(builtins, 'print')('will this work?')
will this work?
```

For custom functions, your approach using `globals`, would work

```
>>> def myprint(*args, **kwargs):
...     print(*args, **kwargs)
... 
>>> globals()['myprint']('will this work?')
will this work?
```

**That being said, it is a bad idea to do this as it can cause security issues**

Comment: Thanks this really helped my problem!